# female 6 pin pcie power plug?

Tags: atx

i am looking for a datasheet, or ideally an eagle library, that has a female 6 pin pcie power plug, like this:[image]

as easy as it seems, i cannot seem to find ANYTHING online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Molex 45718-0002](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0457180002_PCB_HEADERS.xml) connector -- refer to their [mechanical drawings](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/457180002_sd.pdf) for the dimensions and recommended footprint.

There's also a right-angle version of this connector -- [Molex 45558-0003](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0455580003_PCB_HEADERS.xml).

Comment: The recommended footprint is the hole pattern required on the printed circuit board to accommodate the connector.